# HTML and CSS display table error

Tags: html, css

I am creating a web site. This has a menu bar on the left and main content next to it. The problem is if the main part contains something else than plain text then its size has an effect of the starting point of the left menu bar.
Here is a screenshot:
http://kepmegosztas.com/img/0c8013ce70931aad975d91fd76c1cb3e/site.png
"The logged in as user1" should start at the top, but its starting point depends on the size (height) of the textarea. The textarea is resizeable, when I resize it, the content of the left menu "follows" it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sitestyle.css" /><title>
         cim1
      </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header">
         cim2
      </div>
      <div id="wrapper">
         <div id="row">
            <div id="left">
               <span>
                  Logged in as user1<br/>
               </span>
               <a href="login.php?logout=1">
                  (logut)<hr/>
               </a>
               <a href="index.php?year=2013&month=1">
                  2013 - 1<br/>
               </a>
               <a href="index.php?year=2012&month=12">
                  2012 - 12<br/>
               </a>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
               <span>
                  <form action="/site/blog.php" method="post">
                     <textarea name="the_text" class="blog">
                     </textarea>
                     <input value="Submit" type="submit" /></form>
               </span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html
{
   height: 100%;
}

body
{
   background-color: #aabbaa;
   margin: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}

div#header
{
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 80%;
   background-color: gray;
   background-color: #889988;
}

div#wrapper
{ 
   display: table;
   table-layout: fixed;
   width: 80%;
   height: 90%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}

div#row
{ 
   display: table-row;
}


div#left
{ 
   display: table-cell;  
   width: 20%;
   background-color: #ccddcc;
   /*list-style: none;*/
}

div#main
{
   display: table-cell;  
   background-color: white;
}

textarea.blog
{
   resize: both;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Do you have any suggestion how to solve this?
Thanks in advance,
Tamas

Answer (score 0):

Your textarea inside of `div#row`. Separate it and it will be ok.
As another solution fix `div#left` to top and set it's height

you set `div#left` and `div#main` as a `table-cell`, so they must have the same heights when resizing. As solution you can add extra layer inside `div#left` and set position for it, or you can try to span vertical cells, but didn't think that is work on layers. Maybe setting of `vertical-align` for `div#left` is kind

Comment: "Your textarea inside of left div#row. Separate it and it will be ok." Could you please be a little bit more specific? As I think the textarea is inside div#main.

Comment: you got struct like `#wrapper`->`#row`->`#left`+`#main`. So you need to isolate `#left` from `#main`.When you scale textarea `#row` scales too and alignment of sibling `div` brokes, because of `table-cell` display - cells can't have different heights

Comment: 1) I made the following change: #row contains only the #main. Now I have two rows, the first contains the #left, the second contains the #main 2) When I remove the #row completely, then the same result as in the original post happens (using firefox 18.0.1)

Comment: why do you use table notation? ain't it simplier to make blocks and then just set `float` and `clear` propeties?

Comment: Well, I used the float thing first, but when changed to html5 I had some problems with it, after googling to it I found that display: table "should" be used.

Comment: there's no html5 and css3 at all. if you want html5 you must use `aside` instead `div#left`.

Comment: you can use this template, to make your own. [Click me](http://htmlbook.ru/layout/rezinovaya-shirina-navigatsiya-sleva)

Comment: Thanks for the link, and your answers! (I think the topic should be still open, since the original question is open.)

Comment: I found this page: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-crossbrowsertechniques/index.html It says articles, aside should be used.

I changed my above html example to use articles and aside, but the error was the same.

Finally I figured out if the "main" (article in the new way) starts with textarea then the error exists, if it start with a new paragraph < p >, < h > then it is OK...

On real webpages this is not an error, because every page starts with a title, but it was hard to figure it out.

Anyway, problem solved, however the reasons are still hidden.

Comment: cells in same row must have the same height. This is your main trouble. Just separate this to cells. Or better didn't use table's rows and cells displays.